# Scrapy detect if Xpath not exists

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I've been trying to make my first crawler and i've acomplished what i needed ( get the 1º shop and 2º shop shipping infos and prices ) but with 2 crawlers instead of 1 because i've a big stopper here.

When there'are more than 1 shop the output result is:

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//li[@class="container list-display-box__list__container"]/div/div/div/div/div[@class="shipping"]/p//text()').extract()
Out[1]: 
[u'ENV\xcdO 3,95\u20ac ',
 u'ENV\xcdO GRATIS',
 u'ENV\xcdO GRATIS',
 u'ENV\xcdO 4,95\u20ac ']
```

To get only the second result i'm using:

```
In [2]: response.xpath('//li[@class="container list-display-box__list__container"]/div/div/div/div/div[@class="shipping"]/p//text()')[1].extract()
Out[2]: u'ENV\xcdO GRATIS'
```

But when there's no second results ( only 1 shop ) i'm getting:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And the crawler skip the full page even if the other items have data ...

After trying several times i've decided to do a fast solution to get the result, 2 crawlers 1 for first shops and the other for the second one but right now i want to do it clean in only 1 crawler.

Some help, tip or advice will be appreciated, that's my first try making a recursive crawler with scrapy, kinda like it.

There's the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from Guapalia.items import GuapaliaItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
class GuapaliaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "guapalia"
    allowed_domains = ["guapalia.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.guapalia.com/perfumes?page=1',
        'https://www.guapalia.com/maquillaje?page=1',
        'https://www.guapalia.com/cosmetica?page=1',
        'https://www.guapalia.com/linea-de-bano?page=1',
        'https://www.guapalia.com/parafarmacia?page=1',
        'https://www.guapalia.com/solares?page=1',
        'https://www.guapalia.com/regalos?page=1',
    )
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='js-pager']/a[contains(text(),'Siguientes')]"),follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='list-display__item list-display__item--product']/div/a[@class='col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-12 clickOnProduct']"),callback='parse_articles',follow=True),
    )
    def parse_articles(self, response):
        item = GuapaliaItem()
        articles_urls = response.url
        articles_first_shop = response.xpath('//div[@class="container-fluid list-display-box--best-deal"]/div/div/div/div[@class="retailer-logo autoimage-container"]/img/@title').extract()
        articles_first_shipping = response.xpath('//div[@class="container-fluid list-display-box--best-deal"]/div/div/div/div[@class="shipping"]/p//text()').extract()
        articles_second_shop = response.xpath('//li[@class="container list-display-box__list__container"]/div/div/div/div/div/img/@title')[1].extract()
        articles_second_shipping = response.xpath('//li[@class="container list-display-box__list__container"]/div/div/div/div/div[@class="shipping"]/p//text()')[1].extract()
        articles_name = response.xpath('//div[@id="ProductDetail"]/@data-description').extract()
        item['articles_urls'] = articles_urls
        item['articles_first_shop'] = articles_first_shop
        item['articles_first_shipping'] = articles_first_shipping
        item['articles_second_shop'] = articles_second_shop if articles_second_shop else 'N/A'
        item['articles_second_shipping'] = articles_second_shipping
        item['articles_name'] = articles_name
        yield item
```

Basic output of crawler with the right format when there're more than 1 shop:

```
2017-09-21 09:53:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.guapalia.com/zen-edp-vaporizador-100-ml-75355> (referer: https://www.guapalia.com/perfumes?page=1)
2017-09-21 09:53:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.guapalia.com/zen-edp-vaporizador-100-ml-75355>
{'articles_first_shipping': [u'ENV\xcdO GRATIS'],
 'articles_first_shop': [u'DOUGLAS'],
 'articles_name': [u'ZEN edp vaporizador 100 ml'],
 'articles_second_shipping': u'ENV\xcdO 3,99\u20ac ',
 'articles_second_shop': u'BUYSVIP',
 'articles_urls': 'https://www.guapalia.com/zen-edp-vaporizador-100-ml-75355'}
```

The problem is when doesn't exists a second shop because my code on the field second shop

IndexError: list index out of range

SOLUTION Thanks to @Tarun Lalwani

```
def parse_articles(self, response):
    item = GuapaliaItem()
    articles_urls = response.url
    articles_first_shop = response.xpath('//div[@class="container-fluid list-display-box--best-deal"]/div/div/div/div[@class="retailer-logo autoimage-container"]/img/@title').extract()
    articles_first_shipping = response.xpath('//div[@class="container-fluid list-display-box--best-deal"]/div/div/div/div[@class="shipping"]/p//text()').extract()
    articles_second_shop = response.xpath('//li[@class="container list-display-box__list__container"]/div/div/div/div/div/img/@title')
    articles_second_shipping = response.xpath('//li[@class="container list-display-box__list__container"]/div/div/div/div/div[@class="shipping"]/p//text()')
    articles_name = response.xpath('//div[@id="ProductDetail"]/@data-description').extract()
    if len(articles_second_shop) > 1:
        item['articles_second_shop'] = articles_second_shop[1].extract()
    else:
        item['articles_second_shop'] = 'Not Found'
    if len(articles_second_shipping) > 1:
        item['articles_second_shipping'] = articles_second_shipping[1].extract()
    else:
        item['articles_second_shipping'] = 'Not Found'
    item['articles_urls'] = articles_urls
    item['articles_first_shop'] = articles_first_shop
    item['articles_first_shipping'] = articles_first_shipping
    item['articles_name'] = articles_name
    yield item
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the result in a variable first. Then you can take decision based on its length

```
texts = response.xpath('//li[@class="container list-display-box__list__container"]/div/div/div/div/div[@class="shipping"]/p//text()')

if len(texts) > 1:
   data = texts[1].extract()
elif len(text) == 1:
   data = texts[0].extract()
else
   data ="Not found"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly !! ( and very logic answer, coffee time ).